# How to fix half page scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a website where you can scroll between entire page heights of content, but currently with multiple increments of the mouse wheel it will scroll multiple times, this is not an issue however until the site is scrolling between the last two pages where it will scroll like a normal website and won't scroll down to the final page. Would this be able to be fixed with a delay to input or another solution? And how would I go about achieving this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.page');
    var dir = 'up';
    var div = 0;
    $(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll wheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            dir = 'down';
        } else {
            dir = 'up';
        }
        div = -1;
        divs.each(function(i){
            if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                div = i;
            }
        });
        if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
            div--;
        }
        if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
            div++;
        }
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);
    });
 $(window).on('load', function() {

 $(this).impulse({

 extent: $(window).height(),
 tempo: 150,
 method: 'linear',
 delay: true
 });
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.page {
 height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="page" style="background-color:blue;">
   </div>
   <div class="page"style="background-color:black;">
   </div>
   <div class="page"style="background-color:green;">
   </div>
   <div class="page"style="background-color:yellow;">
   </div>
 </body>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
 <script src="js/pagescroller.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but you might benefit from using a plugin such as [scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify).